# prisma throws an error when using relation about array field

Tags: mongodb, prisma

I am using prisma with Mongodb.

the users field in Conversation model causes an error in the picture.
If I set the users field to

```js
users User @relation(fields: [userIds], references: [id])
```

it doesn't throw the error.

```js
model User {
  id              String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email           String   @unique
  hashedPassword  String
  conversationIds String[] @db.ObjectId

  conversation Conversation[]
}

model Conversation {
  id      String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userIds String[] @db.ObjectId
  users User[] @relation(fields: [userIds], references: [id])
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a third table for a N-N relation in prisma, this is the idea, modify as you wish.

Here a link of the official prisma doc: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-schema/data-model/relations/many-to-many-relations

```
model User {
  id              String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email           String   @unique
  hashedPassword  String
  conversationIds String[] @db.ObjectId

  conversation Conversation[]
}

model Conversation {
  id      String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userIds String[] @db.ObjectId
  users User @relation(fields: [userIds], references: [id])
}

model UserConversation {
  user_id String?          @db.Char(36)
  conversation_id String   @db.Char(36)
  
  @@id(name: "UserConversation_id", [user_id, conversation_id])
}
```